# CKSyncEngine.RecordZoneChangeBatch and the CKSyncEngineDelegate protocol

Tags: cloudkit

I'm having some trouble with the following function from the CKSyncEngineDelegate protocol.

```
func nextRecordZoneChangeBatch(_ context: CKSyncEngine.SendChangesContext, 
    syncEngine: CKSyncEngine) async -> CKSyncEngine.RecordZoneChangeBatch? {
```

The sample code from the documentation is

```
func nextRecordZoneChangeBatch(
_ context: CKSyncEngine.SendChangesContext, 
syncEngine: CKSyncEngine
) async -> CKSyncEngine.RecordZoneChangeBatch? {

// Get the pending record changes and filter by the context's scope.
let pendingChanges = syncEngine.state.pendingRecordZoneChanges
    .filter { context.options.zoneIDs.contains($0) }


// Return a change batch that contains the corresponding materialized records.
return await CKSyncEngine.RecordZoneChangeBatch(
    pendingChanges: pendingChanges) { self.recordFor(id: $0) }
}
```

`init?(pendingChanges: [CKSyncEngine.PendingRecordZoneChange], recordProvider: (CKRecord.ID) -> (CKRecord?))`  works fine for the sample app which only has one record type, but it seems incredible inefficient for my app which has a dozen different record types. The recordProvider gives you a CKRecord.ID, but not the CKRecord.RecordType. Searching each record type for a matching ID seems very inefficient.

Doesn't the `CKSyncEngine.PendingRecordZoneChange` contain an array of CKRecords, not just CKRecord.IDs? According to the documentation `CKSyncEngine.RecordZoneChangeBatch` has a recordsToSave property, but Xcode reports `'CKSyncEngine.PendingRecordZoneChange' has no member 'recordsToSave'`

I'm looking for someway to get the CKRecords from syncEngine.state.pendingRecordZoneChanges.

Comment: Similar question can be found here: https://github.com/apple/sample-cloudkit-sync-engine/issues/12#issue-2117656211

Comment: Why do you need to know the record type? You are given a `CKRecord.ID`. From that you must return the corresponding `CKRecord`. The code in the documentation (as shown in your question) references the unknown call `self.recordFor(id: $0)`. `CKDatabase` has a couple of methods for getting a `CKRecord` from a `CKRecord.ID`. Or you can use `CKFetchRecordsOperation` to get records for an ID.